# Cardinality: $\left|\Bbb N^{\{1,2\}}\right| = \left|\Bbb N^{\{1,2,3\}}\right|$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Left $F$ be the set of functions from $\{1,2\}$ to $\Bbb N$ and $G$ be the set of functions from $\{1,2,3\}$ to $\Bbb N$, prove that $\left|F\right| = \left|G\right|$.

Seems intuitive to me that the sets are cardinal equivalent as $\aleph_0^2 = \aleph_0^3$.
I've been trying to write a proof that is not based on cardinal number arithmetic. My approach was to show that $\left|F\right|\le\left|G\right|$ and $\left|G\right|\le\left|F\right|$ then according to Schröder–Bernstein theorm $\Rightarrow \left|F\right|=\left|G\right| \Rightarrow F\sim G$ .

It is clear that $\{1,2\}\subset\{1,2,3\}$ therefore $F\subseteq G$ therefore $\left|F\right|\le\left|G\right|$.
Another explanation is that for every $f\in F$ we can match $g\in G$ such as:
$$g(x) = 
\begin{cases}
f(x) + 1 & x\in\{1,2\} \\
0  & x\in \{3\}
\end{cases}$$

I need help to prove the second part.

Comment: *Hint:* another way to think of $\mathbb N^{\{1,\ldots,n\}}$ is as the cartesian product $\mathbb N^{n}$. So if you can give an embedding $\mathbb N^2\to\mathbb N^1$, you should have no problem generalizing this to an embedding $\mathbb N^3 \to\mathbb N^2$.

Comment: $F$ is not a subset of $G$. A function defined on $\{1, 2\}$ is not defined at $3$, so it's not an element of $G$

Comment: Your second explanation does work, but adding $1$ to $f(x)$ in the case of $x\in \{1,2\}$ is not necessary, so it only obfuscates the argument.

Comment: @Couchy It's a nice way to think about it. I think the projection map will show this easily, right?

Comment: @jjagmath Thanks for both of your notes, It is quite confusing to think of functions as members of sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: For $f\in\Bbb N^{\{1,2,3\}}$ define $\hat f\in\Bbb N^{\{1,2\}}$ by setting $\hat f(1)=f(1)$ and $\hat f(2)=2^{f(2)}\cdot3^{f(3)}$. Show that the map $f\mapsto\hat f$ is injective.

Comment: It actually was my way of thinking. I came up with $\hat f(2)={f(2)}\cdot{f(3)}$ but then realized that it isn't sufficient. I didn't know the trick you've used, how can you be sure that $\hat f(2)=2^{f(2)}\cdot3^{f(3)}$ will never result in the same number?

Comment: @ch0wner: The [unique factorization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic).

Comment: Nice! I will surely read it.

Comment: So it is just a coincidence that you chose 2 and 3 as prime numbers? There are more possible answers such as $\hat f(2)=5^{f(2)}\cdot7^{f(3)}$ etc.

Comment: @ch0wner: They’re a natural choice, since they’re the first two primes, but yes, you could use any pair of distinct primes.

Comment: Math is awesome!